# how to access console for .js filetype

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Having trouble viewing/using the console for a javascript file.  How to I check the console if it is for a standalone script versus a full html/web site file?

I know how to do this for a js script used within a html file - just access firebug or dev tools on the browser - but when I try this with filename.js, it simply displays the code with no console output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [node.js](http://nodejs.org/).

With node installed, standalone javascript files can be launched from the command line:

```
node filename.js
```

This assumes your script doesnt use any browser-specific calls, like 'alert'.